# Git diff to alert hacks

Tags: git, backup, git-diff

We're using Git for source control and Beanstalkapp.com as our remote repository.  Using Beanstalk, we're able to deploy to our Rackspace Cloud Sites account via sftp (they do not support SSH).  While this works fine, we need some assurance that our sites are not updated without our knowledge (hacks) directly on the server.  I know we can do a hash of all of the directories/files to see if there's a change, but I am looking for a more robust way to identify what has changed.   I've come up with the following approach, which I feel can be improved upon by people with more experience...

The following would be in a shell script on the local machine and run hourly via cron:

- Create new Git branch "backup"
- Switch to Branch using "git checkout backup"
- Use SFTP to download all files
- Add files to branch "git add --all"
- Commit files to backup branch "git commit -m 'backup process'"
- Diff branches "git diff master..backup"
- Email results if differences found.
- Switch back to master branch

Comment: Since there's a clear history of what was checked in/modified in Git (and you don't allow rebasing), I don't see how you wouldn't notice subtle changes to parts of your code just with the stock Git server.

Comment: Using Git for this seems like overkill. All you *really* want is a hash. If anything is different from what you expect, then you can do a more detailed investigation.

Comment: Greg, this is a good point too.  I'm concerned though about too many alerts without a good list of changes.

Comment: If you're looking for changes on your web site that you didn't make, then *any* alert should be cause for serious concern. I wouldn't worry about too many when just 1 is too many.

Comment: @greg-hewgill, True!  I can try a hash check and run the sftp/git diff stuff manually if I am alerted of some change.

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting idea, one you can do this without creating a branch.  On your local machine:

- Check out whatever branch is supposed to be deployed
- Download the currently-deployed files from the server to a temporary directory on the local machine
- run the `diff` command to compare the checked-out files to the downloaded server files

Of course generating a hash is simpler, but if someone has access to our server files then they can change the program that generates the hash.

Comment: any reason this is preferable over a branch?

Comment: just keeping your repo clean, is all.